# How to insert data in a database table where foreign key is define with the help of php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named 'programs' where 'Program_name' is the primary key.There is another table named 'po_attainment' where i define 'Program_name' as the foreign key. I made a page where i enter the Program_name and session and is stored in the table named 'programs'. I made an another page where i have calculated the average of some po(program outcome) and stored it in another table named 'po_avg'. Here only the two table 'programs' and 'po_attainment' are in relation. My codes are given below

```
    <?php
    @include("connection.php");
    error_reporting(0);
    $year=$_POST["year"];
    $avg=$_POST["Avg"];
    $avg1=$_POST["Avg1"];
    $program=$_POST["Program_name"];
    if($_POST["submit"])
     {
       $sql="select * from po_avg";
       $rData=mysql_query($sql);
       $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
       $sql="insert into po_avg values('','$avg','$avg1','$year')";
       mysql_query($sql);
     }
        if($avg>=80){
        $sql="select * from po_attainment";
        $rData=mysql_query($sql);
        $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
        $sql="insert into po_attainment values('','PO1','H','$program')";
        mysql_query($sql);
       } 
         else if($avg>=60) {
         $sql="select * from po_attainment";
         $rData=mysql_query($sql);
         $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
         $sql="insert into po_attainment values('','PO1','M','$program')";
         mysql_query($sql);

           }
         else if($avg>=40)
           {
            $sql="select * from po_attainment";
            $rData=mysql_query($sql);
            $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
           $sql="insert into po_attainment values('','PO1','L','$program')";
           mysql_query($sql);
           }
             if($avg1>=80){
             $sql="select * from po_attainment";
             $rData=mysql_query($sql);
             $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
             $sql="insert into po_attainment 
            values('','PO2','H','$program')";
            mysql_query($sql);
            } 
            else if($avg1>=60)
            {
              $sql="select * from po_attainment";
              $rData=mysql_query($sql);
              $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
              $sql="insert into po_attainment 
           values('','PO2','M','$program')";
           mysql_query($sql);

            }
              else if($avg1>=40)
             {
              $sql="select * from po_attainment";
              $rData=mysql_query($sql);
             $res=mysql_fetch_array($rData);
           $sql="insert into po_attainment values('','PO2','L','$program')";
            mysql_query($sql);
            }

           ?>
```

I cannot insert the 'Program_name' in the table 'po_attainment'. How to insert the 'Program_name' in the table 'po_attainment' from the relational table 'programs'.

```
programs table-  p_id(pk),Program_name(pk),year
po_attainment table- att_id(pk),po_name,att_level,Program_name(fk)
po_avg table- po_id(pk),avg,avg1,year.
```

Comment: does the front-end code have a form field with name "Program_name" e.g. `<input name="Program_name">` if so, what is the _type_ (e.g. "text", "hidden", etc.)? Or maybe it is a select-list/drop-down, radio-button or similar control?

Comment: <input type="text" name="Program_name" size="50px" 
                   style="height:30px">

Comment: Is there any way to prevent users from entering a value there that doesn't exist in the programs table?

Comment: at first i have to fillup the "Program_name" and "year"....it will be stored in the 'programs' table...After that i have calculated  the average and it is stored in the 'po_avg' table. Now the above if, else if statement i have given in the code check the average value from the datas stored in the po_avg table and after that the results are stored in the 'po_attainment' table which is related to the 'programs' table. I need that 'Program_name' in the po_attainment table for which program i have calculated the average.

Comment: I understand that, but what if there are only certain records in the **programs** table (e.g. *Program_name* = 'Smith', *Program_name* = 'cats') - what prevents a user from typing in text that isn't matched by any records in that table (E.g. 'dogs')?

Comment: Authenticate user will log in first and after that the user say from B.tech IT have to fill up the program form where he have to enter B.tech IT in the 'Program_name' and year and this data will be stored in the 'programs' table. After clicking the submit button he will enter the page where average calculation will be done. these datas will be stoed in po_avg. And the average value that is stored in the po_avg will be checked by some evaluation formula and the result is stored in another table po_attainment. Now i need that for which program it is calculated.

Comment: There is no such prevention if you give some ideas please share.

Comment: That would be too broad of a topic for the scope of this Q&A. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: can we discuss in some email conversation if any?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, you need to fix this.